# OpenXML nuget package x64 release build error

Tags: c#, uwp, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using OpenXML nuget package for my UWP project

though "**x64 Debug build" is OK**

I am getting build error during **"x64 Release Build"** with OpenXML nuget package

Is their any solution for this problem?

Error Logs:

```
 ....PATH....\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): error : Type 'System.Xml.XmlDocumentXPathExtensions' from assembly 'System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'HtmlWeb.GetCacheHeader(Uri, string, string)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release. [  ....PATH.... ]
          ....PATH....\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): error : Type 'System.Xml.XmlDocumentXPathExtensions' from assembly 'System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'HtmlWeb.GetCacheHeader(Uri, string, string)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release. [  ....PATH....]
          ....PATH....\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): error : Method 'HtmlWeb.GetCacheHeader(Uri, string, string)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'XmlDocumentXPathExtensions.SelectSingleNode(XmlNode, string)' in assembly 'System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release. [  ....PATH....]
          ....PATH....\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): error : Method 'HtmlWeb.GetCacheHeader(Uri, string, string)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'XmlDocumentXPathExtensions.SelectSingleNode(XmlNode, string)' in assembly 'System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release. [ ....PATH.... ]
          ....PATH....\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): error : ILT0005: ' ....PATH....\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\x64\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe
```

Comment: Did you try adding that assembly as a reference?

Comment: no used NuGet package